# Ionic DateTime: Button for multiple ion-datetime created dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use an `ion-button` for each `ion-datetime` created dynamically using `ngFor`.

```
<button ion-button icon-right (click)="picker.open()">
 <ion-datetime #picker pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY"(ionChange)="changeDate()"></ion-datetime>
 <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

For a single ion-datetime, I can use `#picker` and open it from the button using `(click)`.

How is this handled for dynamically created items?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do what you said, and it worked, using the "#picker".
See the below code.

Html:

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-button icon-right *ngFor="let item of items" 
    (click)="picker.open()">
    <ion-datetime #picker pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY" 
      (ionChange)="changeDate($event)"></ion-datetime>
    <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

Ts:

```
export class HomePage {

  items = [1,2,3,4,5];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  changeDate(ev){
    console.log(ev);
  }

}
```

I guess, it will produce your expected result.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `ngFor` isn't present in the button tag but in ion-list tag where ion-items are multiple. This doesn't work in that case.

Comment: why don't you use *ngFor on the ion-item instead? Or do you have to use on the ion-list?

Comment: Oops. I meant I use it on ion-item. It didn't work that way.

Comment: Right then. Let me ask you one more thing. Are you using the button tag  inside the ion-item tag? For example: <ion-list><ion-item><button ion-button>...?

Comment: Yeah. That is what I'm doing.

Comment: This way it really will not work, though, you can do it in two other ways. 1: remove the tag button and use only the ion-item with the type = "button", like that:
<item-item = "button" (click) = "picker.open()" *ngFor = "let item of items">, and inside it, your date-time.
2: remove the ion-item tag, and use only the button, like that:
<button ion-item *ngFor = "let item of items" (click) = "picker.open ()">, and inside it, your date-time. I made myself understood?